# How to Pull Data Value from Array and Input as a Variable

Tags: powershell, csv, variables

I would like to load a csv with server's and an ID for each server. Column 1 being server name, column 2 being an ID string. There will be 40 servers, each with a specific ID string. In my script I want to pull the hostname and then search for it in my array. Once found, I would like to output the ID corresponding to the server name into a variable. I am very new to powershell so please keep that in mind. I work best with examples to work off.

```
$Server = @()
$ID = @()

Import-Csv C:\SecuredFiles\ID.csv | ForEach-Object {$Server += $_.Server ; 
$ID += $_.ID}

$ServerName = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {hostname}

if ($Server -contains $ServerName)
  {
    $Where = [array]::IndexOf($Server, $ServerName)
    $InputID = $ID[$Where]
  }

Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\MyFolder\App.exe' "-id $InputID -d C:\MyFolder"
```

I've dug into this for a few hours and I know I am working harder than needed but I am stubborn and like to find answers myself but I am lost and have a migraine lol maybe I am doing it completely wrong though.

I tried it with various formatting but got different errors like "Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definiton" even though it was clearly there. My current error though is "Missing statement block after if ( condition )" for the beginning of the "If" statement. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why pull it out of the array? use it in place and you don't need to manage the extra variable.

Comment: How would the system know which Id to use then for the argument list? Wouldn't I need it to search and match, then pull the associated ID?

Comment: if you know where the item is in an array, you can simply refer to it by `$Collection[$Index].Parameter`. your method works, but seems like an unneeded extra step. however, use what best suits the way you think of the problem! you are the one who must maintain it ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier and more efficient to import your CSV and then work with the custom-object instances returned by it:

```
# Import into an array of custom objects ([pscustomobject]) that have
# both a .Server and an .ID property.
$serversAndTheirIds = Import-Csv C:\SecuredFiles\ID.csv
```

Specifically, building an output array iteratively with `+=` is very in efficient, because arrays are *immutable* data structures and "adding" to them means that a *new* array must be allocated behind the scenes every time.

---

There is no need to use `Invoke-Command` to synchronously invoke a console application - just invoke the application *directly*.

```
$ServerName = hostname # invoke hostname.exe and capture its output
```

---

Use the `Where-Object` *cmdlet* or the PSv4+ `.Where()` *method* to filter a collection:

```
$inputId = $serversAndTheirIds | Where-Object { $_.Server -eq $ServerName } | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID
```

More efficient PSv4+ alternative:

```
$inputId = $serversAndTheirIds.Where({ $_.Server -eq $ServerName }, 'First' }).ID
```

---

Again, to *synchronously* invoke another *console* application, invoke it directly:

```
C:\MyFolder\App.exe -id $InputID -d C:\MyFolder
```

<sup>Note: If the executable path were *quoted*, you'd need to prepend [`&` , the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-).</sup>

Use `Start-Process` only for invoking *GUI applications*, or running programs *asynchronously* or *hidden*.

---

As for **your *syntax problems***:

The code posted in your question as of this writing is syntactically correct and would not cause the error messages you quote.

Here's what *would* cause them:

> `Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definiton`

A script block (`{...}`) without a closing `}` would trigger this error; e.g., if your script contained *only* the following:

```
 { 'foo'   # no closing '}'
```

> `Missing statement block after if ( condition )`

An `if` statement that isn't followed by a script block would trigger this error; e.g., if your script contained *only* the following:

```
 if ($true) # no script block ({ ... }) to follow the conditional
```

Comment: I appreciate the vast amount of information you have given me, granted I don't fully understand some of it, I still greatly appreciate it. I am getting with my mentor to help me look at the suggestions to further explain the in&outs of what you have given me so I understand what and why I am entering the specific code. As for the errors, I am using Visual Studio Code, would that maybe cause these errors? I can potentially open a workspace so you can see it, those are the errors I am getting though, or would it have to do with me using PS5.1?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @Kameron. No, neither the use of Visual Studio Code nor the use of v5.1 would explain the errors.

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to get the ID of a system from an imported CSV file ...

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @"
Name, ID
Srv001, 1001
Srv002, 2002
Srv003, 3003
Srv004, 4004
Srv005, 5005
$env:COMPUTERNAME, 6006
Srv007, 7007
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

($InStuff -match $env:COMPUTERNAME).ID
```

output = `6006`